# Encode CSV file for Sendgrid's Email API

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I am attempting to build a client reporting engine using R/Python, and Sendgrid's Email API.  I can send emails, but the last thing that I need to do is attach a client's CSV report.

I have attempted a number of approaches, including base64 encoding the file and writing the string to disk from R to python, but not luck.  That said, it seems like I am getting stuck on this error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

My code to get there is:

```
with open('raw/test-report.csv', 'rb') as fd:
     b64data = base64.b64encode(fd.read())
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.content = b64data
attachment.filename = "your-lead-report.csv"
mail.add_attachment(attachment)
```

What is confusing is that if I simply replace `b64data` with the line

```
attachment.content = 'TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4gQ3JhcyBwdW12'
```

an email is sent with an attachment.

For reference, I have been using:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python

and

[kitchen sink tutorial](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/mail_example.py#L16)

and haven't had any issues until this final step in my project.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  It's worth noting that my strength is in `R`, but I usually can hack things together in `python` with the help of the internets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert `b64data` to a regular string before assigning it to `attachment.content`. Sendgrid builds a JSON payload which it sends in the requests so it doesn't know how to serialize the value assigned to `attachment.content` which in this case is a `bytestring`.

```
str(b64data,'utf-8')
```

#### References:

- https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/USAGE.md#post-mailsend

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I had played around with variants of this, but nothing in the right sequence.   Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to attach an in memory CSV to a sendgrid email:

```
import base64
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (
    Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName,
    FileType, Disposition)
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

def send_email_with_csv(from_address, to_address, subject, content, dataframe, filename, filetype):
    message = Mail(
        from_email=from_address,
        to_emails=to_address,
        subject=subject,
        html_content=content)
    
    #%% Create buffered csv
    buffer = BytesIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(buffer);
    buffer.seek(0)
    data = buffer.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
    
    #%%
    attachment = Attachment()
    attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
    attachment.file_type = FileType(filetype)
    attachment.file_name = FileName(filename)
    attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
    message.attachment = attachment
    try:
        sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient('API_KEY')
        response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

send_email_with_csv(from_address='sender@sender.com',
                    to_address='example@recipient.com',
                    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
                    content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>',
                    dataframe=df,
                    filename='spreadsheet.csv',
                    filetype='text/csv')
```

Comment: Useful note to save you time: `filetype` must be MIME types like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType, Disposition)

def send_email_with_attachment(api_key, sender_email, recipient_email, subject, html_content, attachment_path):
    message = Mail(
        from_email=sender_email,
        to_emails=recipient_email,
        subject=subject,
        html_content=html_content
    )

    with open(attachment_path, 'rb') as attachment_file:
        attachment_data = attachment_file.read()

    encoded_file = os.path.basename(attachment_path)
    attached_file = Attachment(
        FileContent(attachment_data),
        FileName(encoded_file),
        FileType('application/html'),
        Disposition('attachment')
    )

    message.attachment = attached_file

    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=api_key)
        response = sg.send(message)
        print("Email sent successfully.")
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email.")
        print(str(e))

# Provide your SendGrid API key
api_key = 'YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY'

# Provide the sender and recipient email addresses
sender_email = 'sender@example.com'
recipient_email = 'recipient@example.com'

# Provide the email subject and HTML content
subject = 'Email with HTML attachment'
html_content = '<html><body><h1>Example HTML Email</h1><p>This is an example email with an HTML attachment.</p></body></html>'

# Provide the path to the HTML file you want to attach
attachment_path = 'path/to/attachment.html'

# Send the email
send_email_with_attachment(api_key, sender_email, recipient_email, subject, html_content, attachment_path)

    enter code here
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76325616/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).